# setting the Id of button in Jquery Templates

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-templates

I am creating a Ajax method to call a c# Webmethod. My returned JSON looks like this

[image]

You'll notice that instead of returning d[0], d[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmZon.png) etc, i'm using a keyValuePair to set the Id of the each item, so that I can then set this to the Id of the button. Alas, this is where I need some assistance.

How can i take each id (307, 309 ...) and assign it to the id of a button in a Jquery template.

My Jquery template code is:

```
 <script id="approvaltmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
        <table class="table table-user-information" style="height: 100px;">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="approved by"></i> ${UserName}</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span id="approvedDate"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="approved date"></i> ${parseJsonDate(EnteredDate)}</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span id="approveComment"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="comment"></i> ${Comment}</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </script>
    <script id="audittmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
        <table class="table table-user-information" style="height: 100px;">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="comment by"></i> ${UserName}</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span id="auditDate"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="approved date"></i> ${parseJsonDate(AuditDate)}</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span id="auditComment"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="comment"></i> ${Comments}</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        <button id= />
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </script>
```

***EDIT***
Call being made, which generates the template:

```
success: function(msg) {
                    // Need to work out a way of refreshing the screen
                    console.log(msg);
                    $.each(msg.d, function(index, item) {
                        $('#approvaltmpl').tmpl(item).appendTo('#approvalResults');
                        $('.button_class').attr('id', index);
                    });
```

***EDIT***
After applying the above code, provided by #anvlasop, i still get all the buttons producing the same id value, which is the last one in the list.

NOTE values are different, today.

[image]

***EDIT***
this gives me an alert for each d[number]

```
 $.each(msg.d, function (index, item) {

                        $('#violationtmpl').tmpl(item).appendTo('#violationResults');
                        alert(index);

                    });
```

but i cant then apply index to the buttons

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood your question well, then this is what you need:

```
$.each(d, function( index, value ) {
    $('.button_class').attr('id',index); //assing the id to the button

});
```

Comment: so, this applies the last Id of 309 to every button.

Comment: What exactly you want to do?

Comment: So, the screen shot above show three id's 307,308, 309. I need to assign the index to each creation of a button. Your code should work, but for some reason, it need to retain each unique id

Comment: Chaps, i've added a picture of my output. as can be seen, the same value of 214 is being applied to the buttons.

Comment: @anvlasop see screen shot above. If i alert(index) it's fine, but it's not working as expected using the template